# What is the meaning of the traceback?

Tags: python, django, web

I am using  django-email-change-0.2.1 just to change an emailadress in the auth_user-table. When I am going to add the app emailchange in the settings.py. I get an error message!

Actually you can install the app. But I didn't do that in the site-packages of python. I have copied the code into my code of the website.

Root of my Website:
/trunk/website/

In the following path I have installed different apps.
Path:

```
/trunk/website/auth/user/emailchange  
/trunk/website/auth/user/registraiton  
/trunk/website/auth/user/profile
```

The last two apps are working fine. I just want to add the last app for my registration. To change the email address of an user with the app  "emailchange", so I am going to send a a verifaction link when the user is changeing his emailadress.

In my settings.py to run/install the app (model) I added:

```
Insalled_apps= {
'auth.user.emailchange'
}
```

But I am getting this errormessage when I add the app and call any site of my website!

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  91.                         request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  215.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  244.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  239.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/workspace/website/trunk/website/urls.py" in <module>
  5. admin.autodiscover()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  24.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/trunk/website/auth/user/emailchange/admin.py" in <module>
  33. admin.site.register(cache.get_model('email_change', 'EmailChangeRequest'), EmailChangeRequestAdmin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in register
  76.         for model in model_or_iterable:

Exception Type: TypeError at /start/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas? Why do I have this message?

Comment: What is 'auth.user.emailchange'?

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope you guys know what I mean!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Insalled_apps= {
'auth.user.emailchange'
}
```

is wrong in many ways. First, it's not valid Python syntax (curly brackets are for making dicts, not lists) and secondly it's not even close to the valid way of adding an app to a Django settings.py file, which is something like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'foos',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
 )
```

So basically fix those things and get back to us. Oh, and could you please also consider copying and pasting code into questions so you don't make mistakes typing them in again?

Comment: [offtopic] It's valid syntax for creating a set in Python 3.